# linking  openssl so libraries with android make file 

Tags: curl, android-ndk, openssl, libcurl

I have built the curl and openssl separately for android ndk using the following link 
openssl https://github.com/eighthave/openssl-android

curl http://thesoftwarerogue.blogspot.in/2010/05/porting-of-libcurl-to-android-os-using.html#comment-form

and I have also tested simple curl code  for http GET which can use the  libcurl.so , now How to use the openssl library(libssl.so,libcrypto.so) in the curl code to try the https

Pls provide some insight on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to configure libcurl to enable SSL in general and to use OpenSSL in particular. Use Configure script to prepare `curl_config.h`. Make sure the following defines are set there (for Android and OpenSSL):

```
#define HAVE_LIBSSL 1
#define USE_OPENSSL 1
#define USE_SSLEAY 1
#define HAVE_OPENSSL_CRYPTO_H 1
#define HAVE_OPENSSL_ERR_H 1
#define HAVE_OPENSSL_PEM_H 1
#define HAVE_OPENSSL_PKCS12_H 1
#define HAVE_OPENSSL_RSA_H 1
#define HAVE_OPENSSL_SSL_H 1
#define HAVE_OPENSSL_X509_H 1
```

Recompile lib curl with this defines. Now you can access https links.